# Loop Subviews of a UIView

Tags: ios, loops, subview

I am creating bunch of subviews of type STlater in a UIView (STlater is also of type UIView)

and there is UIButton with below click event, i want to loop thru all the subviews and setup some values but it gives SIGABRT error. Please help.

`enter code here`

```
-(IBAction)nextClick:(id)sender
{
    for (STlater *stv in self.subviews) {
        //stv.lblTime.text=@"7:00";
        [stv setInitValues:@"hello"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check that *stv* is an instance of STlater, as the UIButton instance in subviews probably doesn't have the *setInitValues:* method.

```
for (STlater *stv in self.subviews) {
    if ( [stv isKindOfClass:[STLater class]] ) {
         [stv setInitValues:@"hello"];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks greyhands, works perfectly now. But I thought when i said STlater it would bring only subviews of kind STlater.

Comment: Nope, subviews is an array with all the views inside a view (and UIButton inherits from UIview). Glad it helped =)